# Python script into model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, python-script-tool

I have a toolbox to share with my collegaues, it includes a model and imported python script. This script is also imported to the model in the end of session.
When I share this toolbox to another PC, there is a problem in it: the model seems to be broken like here:

[image]

The solution is to edit model and manually set the path to a script, which is in the same toolbox or drag and drop it to a model. 
Is there any kind of tool or calculator that will run my script without any relationships to location of script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check 2 things:

- Is the script imported in the script tool? Right-click it in the Catalog > Import Script.
- Also, in the Model properties, make sure the 'Store relative pathnames (instead of absolute paths)' box is checked: right-click the model in the Catalog > Properties > General tab.

Comment: Script is imported already. As for relative paths, thank for advice!